# How to migrate Logins from SQL Server to Azure SQL DB

Tags: sql-server, ssis, azure-sql-server

I want to migrate SQL Server logins to Azure SQL.
I tried using SQL Server Integration Service "Transfer Logins Links" but it throws "Keyword or statement option 'default_database' is not supported in this version of SQL Server."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a user in master database and set new password for the login.

Comment: What is the additional insight this answer provides in comparison to the older and accepted one? This reads like a summary of that.

Answer (score 0):

No matter which ways migrate SQL Server to Azure SQL(single database), DMA or DMS, they all don't support migrate the logins or uses.

We must re-create the logins/users manually in the new Azure SQL database. There isn't a way can achieve that for now.

If you migrate SQL Server to SQL Server on Azure Virtual Machines(managed instance), you can reference this documnet: [Migrate SQL Server logins with Data Migration Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-migrateserverlogins?view=sql-server-ver15).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can we migrate logins and user to Azure SQL Managed Instance using Azure DMS online?

Comment: @SarveshPandey Just from the document, not all the logins can be migrate, still has 
 some limits.